# Changing Text of Button as well fadetoggle function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fadeout

```
<button id="myButton" class="comment-submit button small green">Play Video</button>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#div1").fadeToggle(3000);
    });
});
```

So i got this code, which basicly pops up a video when i hit the playbutton, Works like a charm but:

I want the text of the button to change to `Hide Video`, once they clicked "Play Video", and back to "Play Video" if they click "Hide Video"

I found a bunch of solutions, but the problem is, im a jquery nub, even worse, im pretty new to web building.

So where should i put the code, for example this solution:

```
$('.SeeMore2').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass('SeeMore2');
    if($this.hasClass('SeeMore2')){
        $this.text('See More');         
    } else {
        $this.text('See Less');
    }
});
```

so confused of what im missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/n1k1ch/V4u5X/37/)

HTML:

```
<button id="myButton" class="videoHidden">Play Video</button>
<div id="videoWrap">Video is here</div>
```

CSS:

```
#videoWrap {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #9ff;
    display: none;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myButton').click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $("#videoWrap").fadeToggle();//or .toggle() for instant showing/hiding
        $this.toggleClass('videoHidden');

        if($this.hasClass('videoHidden')){
            $this.text('Play Video');           
        } else {
            $this.text('Hide Video');
        }
    });
});
```

So:

1. Once document is loaded, you have a button which has "Play Video"
   text and "videoHidden" class
2. When you click on the button, it toggles "videoHidden" class on the button (adds if
   not exists or removes if exists). It helps you to save some "state" of video playing.
3. Then you use current "state" to change button's text to corresponding value ("Play Video" if
   video isn't playing, "Hide Video" if video is playing)

---

### Edited

There is an error here http://biready.visseninfinland.nl/testing-2/:

At line 467 there is erroneous script

```
<script>
    $('#myButton').click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $("#videoWrap").slideToggle();</p>
<p>        $this.toggleClass('videoHidden');</p>
<p>     if($this.hasClass('videoHidden')){
            $this.text('Play Video');           
        } else {
            $this.text('Hide Video');
        }
    });
</script>
```

You should remove `</p>` and `<p>` from it

---

### Edited 2

The last version of script (need to perform attaching handler within `$(document).ready()`):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myButton').click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $("#videoWrap").slideToggle();
        $this.toggleClass('videoHidden');
        if($this.hasClass('videoHidden')){
            $this.text('Play Video');
        } else {
            $this.text('Hide Video');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: for some reason i cannot get this to work. might it be my wordpress theme interfering? i work with Avada Theme.

Comment: Do html of button and div equals to answered (class of button and id of div)?

Comment: Yeah, i took ur code line for line and placed it within the corresponding places, but it simply wont work:(

Comment: Used the new script, removed the </p> and <p>, saved it off, opened the page and...nothing:( the button wont change, the video wont show up. Im so clueless.

Comment: It does give me a unsuspected error: Uncaught Error : Object [object Object] has no method 'live'. No idea or my videofile, which is a customized YouTube video imported with vtubetools.com generated code, conflicts in any of this.

Comment: This error is inside "main.js" and does not related to this question.

Comment: If you want, i could give you login of my wp-site, maybe a look under the hood will clearify things?

Comment: where to? i cant find ur email address:S

Comment: nikita.cherevkov@gmail.com

Comment: added a account for you, u should have login in ur email

Comment: See Edited2, change script in that way

Comment: Awesome, that surely did the trick. now i got one problem left. IE... when i click play video, it shows up perfect, but for some reason the video keeps playing after i press the hide video button. how could i resolve this?

Comment: Hey Nikita, i mailed u a followup request to ur email adres.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be more easy by this code.

```
 <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#click').click(function(){
                    $("#videoWrap").slideToggle();
                    var $this = $(this);
                      $this.html() == "Play Video" ?  $this.html("Hide video") :  $this.html("Play Video");
            });
        });
</script>
```